# Autocad- Aligning 4 corners to 4 different lines

Tags: autocad, positions-measurement, surveying

To explain the situation, I am creating a site plan (using Autocad 2022), I have a building that is angled within a complex property. The 4 corners of the building are dimensioned to a property line(PL). What I did, was offset a line from each of the PLs that had a dimension attached to it at the appropriate value. I now have 4 lines at different angles and I need each corner to be touching one of the lines. The align tool only works for 2 reference points really and even that does not do so well at attaching to 2 points. I could manually play around, but there has to be some what to select a point and a line it should attach to for each of the 4 corners.

Update: Here is a snip of one of the situations I am trying to resolve. I need the corner with the red circle to sit somewhere on the red line, the corner with the green circle to sit on the green line, and so on for the cyan and white. I believe there should only be one way that all of the corners can be sit on their respected line at once. [image] This image shows after I have already tried to quickly do this manually.

Anyone have any advice on this situation?

Comment: Post a properly cropped screen grab. This doesn't seem to be AutoCAD specific question - it seems to be a basic drafting problem.

Comment: Agree with @Transistor that you really need to post a sketch, screen capture, or picture of the problem in order to receive some good advice.  From the basic sounds of things, I would be looking at your resulting offset rhombus and placing a rectangle with one corner where you want it.  I am guessing I would probably then rotate the rectangle to align with one of the offset lines.  I would then either stretch or scale it to get the corner of the rectangle on the offset line to where it needs to be.  I would then stretch the remaining to rectangle corners to where they need to be

Comment: Also, it's not really clear what the end result should be. Are you trying to find the maximum size building you can fit in the site or do you have the size of the building but have some other constraints?

Comment: I'll try to get a snip later today, but using the property lines that Forward Ed's answer showed, imagine those lines are setup as the distance lines to the 4 corners of the building, the building is existing and rectilinear with all 90 degree corners. I need to rotate the building so that each corner lands within the respected line. For this instance it is crucial as the goal is to add in an addition to the existing building but avoiding an easement that runs through the property. Hopefully that helps, I'll try to add an images later today.

Comment: One more note, I have an existing survey pdf with everything dimensions and labeled, but no CAD to use. And the drawing is not to scale/accurate for the dimensions specified so I can't just trace the pdf.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. You seem to be rotating a building that is already built. How does that work? What makes you think there's a valid geometric solution that will have each corner sit on its respective line?

Comment: @Transistor I'm not rotating the building so much as placing it where it should be. What I need is to accurately place it so I can save ze an addition without infringing on the easement (yellow dash-dot line). With the survey stating that each of the corners is a set distance from the respected property line, I am merely trying to accurately place the building so that each of the corners is the correct distance. I know this can be done manually, but there has to be some way that it can be done through a command of some sort.

Comment: there is no automated press a single button command.  Even if you used Constraints, this would be an over constrained situation most likely.  Part of the problem you will face is degree of accuracy in the survey and too many dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume for now that your property line in magenta are laid out as followed:

[image]

Now we offset the property lines to define a boundary the building has to fit in.  Lets also assume that the lower property line is your street frontage and therefore requires a larger offset (mainly so it is not all equal offsets).  The re line represent your parallel offsets:

[image]

Depending on what your ultimate goal is with the building placement your solution may vary from this point.  I would start by drawing a rectangle with the corner coincident one of the other corners.  Lets take the top left:

[image]

I would then rotate the yellow rectangle with the top left corner as my base point.  I would rotate using the reference option.  My reference line would be the two end points of the top rectangle.  I would then choose any point on the top red offset line to rotate to.  When done properly it should align as follows:

[image]

Now note in this situation the top right corner of the rotated rectangle is now outside the offset line.  It could also have been short of the property line.  To get this in the right position I would select the rectangles two right corner grip points at the same time and drag the top right one to the intersection of the two red offset lines:

[image]

If done right it should look like this:

[image]

I would repeat this process for the left side, except this time you want to drag the two left corner grips such that the bottom left corner goes to the intersect of the left red offset line the the bottom yellow rectangle line.  when done right it should look like this:

[image]

Now depending what your needs are, you may need to have the building touching front and back offset lines.  Just repeat the steps above as needed and you can get something that looks like the following:

[image]

There are multiple solutions on how to size the building.  Try a few different placements and see which one suits your needs.  It will also give you good practice with CAD.

Here is an option with all four corners on at least 1 line:

[image]

Note:  For this example it is not the only solution.